# How to get my second-hand, factory reset, 2008 iMac to work?

Tags: hard-drive, macos, imac, reboot

Good day,

***1. The Setup***

I recently got a 2008 imac from a friend who reset it to factory settings prior to giving it to me. When I tried to turn it on it brought me to a OS X Utilities window. In this window there are 4 options to choose from:

- *Restore from time machine backup* - When clicking this, it states no Time Machine backups were found.
- *Reinstall OS X* - When clicking this, it leads me to the proper steps to install OS X El Captain (released from apple in 2015). After giving my Apple ID and Password it will give me a error saying "This item is temporarily unavailable". From there I am unable to proceed.
- *Get Help Online* - Prompts me to a website with steps on how to reinstall OS X but do not help me with my specific situation.
- *Disk Utility* - Opens the following window:[image: window]

***2. What I understand***

- The OS is completely gone from this mac (as are some basic terminal commands such as open and sudo)
- The OS is not available from the app store as of this date (4/21/2020)
- I need the OS in order to have the Mac working
- To get the OS I need to boot the OS X El Captain program via some USB or external hard drive

***3. Attempts I've made***

- I have downloaded a file titled InstallMacOSX.dmg from this link
- I have a 8 Gb USB that has been formatted to be able to transfer the InstallMacOSX.dmg file from my computer onto the USB
- I did a successful transfer using a program called TransMac
- I Connected the USB onto the Mac
- I went to Disk Utilities and restored the HD Macintosh drive found in the Internal drive successful which caused the HD Macintosh to be renamed to "Install OS X"

***4. What went wrong***

- At this point the next step is to partition the USB with the following settings: CURRENT = 1 PARTITION), (FORMAT = MAC OSX EXTENDED JOURNALED) and SCHEME = GUID PARTITION MAP. BUT I cannot directly change the CURRENT or SCHEME settings in this mac. Here is an Image of what I get when I partition:[image]
- I understand that we need to partition to get a folder called Untitled. Then click on the folder and restore the "Install OS X" drive into this new folder. Following that we reboot the computer, hold the alt key and select the external USB drive to begin downloading the El Captain OS X. It will take you to a window where the downloading process can begin.
- By not doing so, when I simply reboot the computer, hold alt, and then select the external USB drive, it shows the Apple logo for over 5 minutes, then it turns to black for a couple seconds, then it makes the reboot noise, and finally it it leaves me with a white blank display and stays like that.

***5. My Questions***

How do I partition the USB correctly using this 2008 iMac? Is there something else that I did wrong? Is there more information that you would need from me?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Make sure the date/time are correct.  In Terminal issue the following command: `sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com` then try reinstalling the OS again.

Comment: @Allan I am unable to use the sudo command. It gives me this result:`sudo:command not found`

Comment: Sorry...if you're in recovery, you don't need the sudo.  Just leave it out

Comment: @Allan Thanks! the command worked and I tried to reinstall the OS and instead of giving me a _This item is temporarily unavailable_ message, it gives me an error that says `AMD-Action:authenticate:SP`. I am not sure where to go from here but thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I’m not sure what that one is, I’ll have to research.

Comment: What I've found is that it's also a date problem.  However, for whatever reason, it has to be set to PST (every time I install macOS it defaults to PST even though I'm EST).  Issue the command `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone` see what you get.